# Why is fiddler showing a 0 for the http post body? Does this look correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

Trying to simply post a string to a web api to make sure it works and the json string doesn't seem to be there even though I can see it in the debugger.. Is there something obvious I am missing ?

```
 RootObject ro = new RootObject();
        ro.JobID = 9999;


        var dataAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro); //there is a json string here
        var content = new StringContent(dataAsString);




        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://localhost:55816");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Jobs/", content);
```

{"Files":null,"JobID":9999,"ReadyForPublish":false,"ScheduledJobID":null}

Comment: What happens if you post `dataAsString` instead of `content`?

Comment: that worked.. I must have copied that code from somewhere.. Not sure why it is creating a new stringContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an `HttpClient` you can directly use the result of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);` as the second argument to the `PostAsJsonAsync`. No need to use the `StringContent`.